# React Native Image can't work sometimes

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I created an [iOS APP](https://github.com/just4fun/uestc-bbs-react-native) for university BBS (built in PHP) with React Native 0.14.

When I send request to fetch user info, I will get a record including filed `avatar`, which has value like `http://bbs.uestc.edu.cn/uc_server/avatar.php?uid=32044&size=middle`.

```
<Image
  style={styles.avatar}
  source={{uri: authrization.avatar}} />
```

It seems like a PHP method (I'm not familiar with PHP), since the value of `avatar` will become `http://bbs.uestc.edu.cn/uc_server/data/avatar/000/03/20/44_avatar_middle.jpg` if I type the original value in the browser.

However, the avatar is not displayed sometimes. See the [screenshot](http://g.recordit.co/Z3RyLrdFTq.gif).

Does the `<Image>` component only support static picture file which ends with `jpg|png|gif`?

Answer (score 2):

That URL returns a redirect. However, the Image component doesn't support redirects.

As a workaround, use a URL that returns the image. If you want support for redirects please consider sending a pull request.

Checked with curl:

```
$ curl -I http://bbs.uestc.edu.cn/uc_server/avatar.php?uid=32044&size=middle
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

Comment: This issue is fixed by https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/192ab663b76dd8e640915c0670830c2de557804f and it was release in RN 0.26.0.

Comment: @talent was this fixed for Android too? It doesnt seem to work for me